# Any support in Spring AMQP to manually retrieve(recover) all unack messages on a channel (equivalent to Basic.recover api)

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, message, amqp, recover

Is there any support in Spring AMQP to manually retrieve(recover) all un-ack messages ?
That is, if I want to leverage feature given by  Basic.recover api (https://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-quickref.html)